# How to make Play 2 Scala work with remote PostgreSQL db server?

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt

My Play app can connect to a MySQL server.

Why can't it connect to a PostgreSQL server?

In project directory...

```
// build.sbt file...

name := "scalaplay1"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `scalaplay1` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws   , specs2 % Test,
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.38"      // This works
  // "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.1-901.jdbc4" // This does not
  )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )  

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

Config file...

```
// conf/application.conf file...

db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver   // This works
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://<my_server>:<port_number>/<db_name>"

#db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver  // This fails (line 48)
#db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://<my_server>:<port_number>/<db_name>"

db.default.username="username"
db.default.password= "password"
```

Here is how Play fails (on the browser)...

```
Configuration error

Cannot connect to database [default]

In /C:/Users/User/IdeaProjects/project/target/scala-2.11/classes/application.conf:48

47. db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver // This fails (line 48)
48. db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://<my_server>:<port_number>/<db_name>"
```

Here is how Play fails (in the terminal)...

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000

Server started, use Alt+D to stop

[success] Compiled in 567ms
[warn] application - Logger configuration in conf files is deprecated and has no effect. Use a logback configuration file instead.
[info] application - Creating Pool for datasource 'default'
[error] application - 

! @6oombhen4 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->

play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:829) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:48) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi.connect(DefaultDBApi.scala:42) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get$lzycompute(DBModule.scala:72) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:62) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DBApiProvider.get(DBModule.scala:58) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81) ~[guice-4.0.jar:na]
Caused by: play.api.Configuration$$anon$1: Configuration error[Exception during pool initialization]
    at play.api.Configuration$.configError(Configuration.scala:178) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.PlayConfig.reportError(Configuration.scala:1048) ~[play_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:69) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource$lzycompute(Databases.scala:124) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.dataSource(Databases.scala:122) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:143) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDatabase.getConnection(Databases.scala:139) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:44) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.DefaultDBApi$$anonfun$connect$1.apply(DefaultDBApi.scala:42) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolInitializationException: Exception during pool initialization
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:542) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.PooledDatabase.createDataSource(Databases.scala:199) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC4 Connection.isValid() method not supported, connection test query must be configured
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.addConnection(BaseHikariPool.java:441) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.initializeConnections(BaseHikariPool.java:540) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.BaseHikariPool.<init>(BaseHikariPool.java:171) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:60) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:48) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:80) ~[HikariCP-2.3.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:58) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool$$anonfun$1.apply(HikariCPModule.scala:54) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192) ~[scala-library-2.11.7.jar:na]
    at play.api.db.HikariCPConnectionPool.create(HikariCPModule.scala:54) ~[play-jdbc_2.11-2.4.6.jar:2.4.6]
```

^ Note that I double checked that the ports were open, that I copy-pasted the endpoint name correctly, that the port number is correct, and that the database name is correct. I made the Postgres instance with Amazon RDS service and I am 100% sure that those four things are correct.

What's the problem (or at least what can you narrow it down to)?

---

Solution: add this to application.conf...

```
#specify a connectionTestQuery. Only do this if upgrading the JDBC-Driver does not help
db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"
```

Or upgrade to the newest driver (don't know how to do that inside SBT)

Comment: Are your app and db in the same security group ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the bottom of the stacktrace (and Play's [Migration Guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Migration24#JDBC-connection-pool)), you should try adding a connectionTestQuery, e.g.

```
db.default.connectionTestQuery = "select 1"
```

Comment: It worked. Also, I am a beginner and all I know is how to copy-paste config stuff from Google and I can't seem to find the most recent PostgreSQL driver for build.sbt . I don't want to have to manually grab jar files off Google.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette you can chose a updated driver version here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql. Also, this was a "bug" with HikariCP and was fixed already: https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/225.

Comment: None of the ones that end in "-jdbc4" are found by SBT. Like I can replace "9.1-901.jdbc4" with "9.2-1003-jdbc4" and I get UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES. I think I'll just stick to the old driver just to make sure everything works with both databases.

Comment: SBT needs to be more like Rails gems where you can specify a range of versions you would be willing to accept and it picks the highest one in that range automatically.

Comment: Also, while I'm complaining, they ought to format these stack traces better.  They look like a wall of text. A row of whitespace between the traces would be nice. Also, the coloration is really ugly. The columns have so much color contrast that the wall of text looks like a series of black, blue, and red stripes. Thank you.

Comment: Well, you can edit your question to add the complete `build.sbt` and also `project\plugins.sbt` so we can see if there is something wrong with SBT resolvers. Declaring any of those versions in a clean projects works to me. About version ranges, see [here about how you can declare them](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Dependencies.html#Ivy+revisions).

Answer (score 0):

Thnaks man. I added these command on application.conf db.default.hikaricp.connectionTestQuery="SELECT TRUE"and works fine.